# JAVA - Read only new lines in a file

Tags: java, file

I am writing a code in Java to read lines from a file. It is required by the problem statement that the code reads the same file multiple times. However, it should only read new lines, without using any flag of any sort. Please suggest ways on how I can approach this. Any ideas are welcome.

Comment: Welcome to the forum of the Telepaths. We are currently analysing your code...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to "only read new lines." To achieve what you're looking to do, I would suggest caching the old version of the file and comparing the new file every time you re-read it with the old cached one. You will be able to detect the new lines and any other change in the file. After you are done analyzing, overwrite the old cache saving the newest read.

Comment: Thank you @Confiqure I just used a read/unread flag as caching was a little overhead for the problem statement in hand.